# How to continuously update line chart with live data

Tags: java, javafx

I am having two line charts, in one of the line chart i.e chart1, i am updating values continuously, in other chart i.e chart2, based on peak values of chart1, i am trying to show the peak values of chart1 in chart2. If peak values(i.e 4 to 10) are in less number then there is no problem, if peak values are more, then my line chart application is becoming too slow.  For continuously updating values in chart1 and chart2 i used Animation timer.

Below is with few peak values
[image]

Below image is having more peak values then my application is hanging
[image]

For better performance how to do with animation timer .

**CODE UPDATE**

In addDataToSeries function i am adding 1600 random values and populating values in chart1.

In addRffDataToSeries function, i am populating peak values in chart2

```
    private void prepareTimeLine() {
    timer = new AnimationTimer() {

        @Override
        public void handle(long l) {
            plotData.addDataToSeries();

        }
    };

}

private void startTimer() {
    timer.start();
}

private void stopTimer() {
    timer.stop();
    System.out.println("  " + lineChart.getData().size());
    System.out.println(" " + series.getData().size());
    if (lineChart.getData().size() > 0) {
        series.getData().remove(0, series.getData().size());
    }
}

private void prepareRffTimeLine() {
    rffTimer = new AnimationTimer() {

        @Override
        public void handle(long l) {
            rffSeries.getData().remove(0, rffSeries.getData().size());
            plotData.addRffDataToSeries();
        }
    };

}

private void startRffTimer() {
    rffTimer.start();
}

private void stopRffTimer() {
    rffTimer.stop();
    if (rffLineChart.getData().size() > 0) {
        rffSeries.getData().remove(0, rffSeries.getData().size());
    }
}

public void addDataToSeries() {

    double x = 0;
    double y = 0;
    int i = 1;

    seriesXData.clear();
    seriesYData.clear();
    for (i = 1; i <= 1596; i++) {
        x = Math.random() * i + 1;
        y = (Math.random() * ((-100) - (-130))) + -130;
        seriesXData.add(new XYChart.Data(x, y));
        seriesYData.add(new XYChart.Data(x, y));
    }

    seriesXData.add(new XYChart.Data(300.0, -60.0));
    seriesXData.add(new XYChart.Data(600.0, -50.0));
    seriesXData.add(new XYChart.Data(900.0, -30.0));
    seriesXData.add(new XYChart.Data(1300.0, -10.0));

    seriesYData.add(new XYChart.Data(300.0, -60.0));
    seriesYData.add(new XYChart.Data(600.0, -50.0));
    seriesYData.add(new XYChart.Data(900.0, -30.0));
    seriesYData.add(new XYChart.Data(1300.0, -10.0));

    Collections.sort(seriesXData, new ArrangeXData());
    Collections.sort(seriesYData, new ArrangeYData());
    series.getData().addAll(seriesXData);

    if (series.getData().size() > 1600) {
        series.getData().remove(0, 1600);
    }


}

public void addRffDataToSeries() {

    Comparator<XYChart.Data<Double, Double>> c = new Comparator<XYChart.Data<Double, Double>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(XYChart.Data<Double, Double> o1, XYChart.Data<Double, Double> o2) {
            return o1.getYValue().compareTo(o2.getYValue());
        }
    };

    int index = Collections.binarySearch(seriesYData, new XYChart.Data<Double, Double>(null, Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(Line.y))), c);

    int insertion_point = -(index + 1);
    if (seriesYData.size() <= 0) {
        return;
    }
    List<XYChart.Data<Double, Double>> res = seriesYData.subList(insertion_point, seriesYData.size());

    for (int ind = 0; ind < res.size(); ind++) {
        for (int pos = Bounds.x; pos > Bounds.y; pos--) {
            rffSeries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(res.get(ind).getXValue(), pos));
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: ... was there supposed to be a question somewhere?

Comment: @specializt OP wants to improve code's performance

Comment: Can you show some of the relevant code?

Comment: i updated my post with code

Comment: @ItachiUchiha almost i used same logic in this [Live Chart Live Update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22089022/line-chart-live-update). Except i have not used  "ExecutorService", "ConcurrentLinkedQueue"  classes.

Answer (score 0):

From what ever source you getting the data from some web service call or reading for some queue. you need to delay the input data. may be a half second delay should be fine. This is because the volume of data coming to the browser is too much, and it is not able to handle the same.

Secondly, make sure you close your connection once your point moves out of the screen, this is reduce the number of open connections and improve performance.