# Making line chart that moves plotted points from top to bottom every second

Tags: java, charts, javafx, linechart

I have a line chart, where 1600 random points are added to series.

After loading data, every 5 seconds, already plotted points should decrease it's y-axis by one point.

Here my problem is I don't know the axis values (x-axis/y-axis values) in series because it's random data.

Suppose if I knew the values; but for processing 1600 values it's time-consuming.

**UPDATE:**

```
 private void prepareTimeLine() {
timer = new AnimationTimer() {

    @Override
    public void handle(long l) {
        addDataToSeries();

    }
};

}

private void startTimer() {
timer.start();
}

private void stopTimer() {
timer.stop();
System.out.println("  " + lineChart.getData().size());
System.out.println(" " + series.getData().size());
if (lineChart.getData().size() > 0) {
    series.getData().remove(0, series.getData().size());
}
}

private void prepareRffTimeLine() {
rffTimer = new AnimationTimer() {

    @Override
    public void handle(long l) {
        rffSeries.getData().remove(0, rffSeries.getData().size());
        addRffDataToSeries();
    }
};

}

private void startRffTimer() {
rffTimer.start();
}

private void stopRffTimer() {
rffTimer.stop();
if (rffLineChart.getData().size() > 0) {
    rffSeries.getData().remove(0, rffSeries.getData().size());
}
}

public void addDataToSeries() {

double x = 0;
double y = 0;
int i = 1;

seriesXData.clear();
seriesYData.clear();
for (i = 1; i <= 1596; i++) {
    x = Math.random() * i + 1;
    y = (Math.random() * ((-100) - (-130))) + -130;
    seriesXData.add(new XYChart.Data(x, y));
    seriesYData.add(new XYChart.Data(x, y));
}

seriesXData.add(new XYChart.Data(300.0, -60.0));
seriesXData.add(new XYChart.Data(600.0, -50.0));
seriesXData.add(new XYChart.Data(900.0, -30.0));
seriesXData.add(new XYChart.Data(1300.0, -10.0));

seriesYData.add(new XYChart.Data(300.0, -60.0));
seriesYData.add(new XYChart.Data(600.0, -50.0));
seriesYData.add(new XYChart.Data(900.0, -30.0));
seriesYData.add(new XYChart.Data(1300.0, -10.0));

Collections.sort(seriesXData, new ArrangeXData());
Collections.sort(seriesYData, new ArrangeYData());
series.getData().addAll(seriesXData);

if (series.getData().size() > 1600) {
    series.getData().remove(0, 1600);
}


}

public void addRffDataToSeries() {

Comparator<XYChart.Data<Double, Double>> c = new Comparator<XYChart.Data<Double, Double>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(XYChart.Data<Double, Double> o1, XYChart.Data<Double, Double> o2) {
        return o1.getYValue().compareTo(o2.getYValue());
    }
};

int index = Collections.binarySearch(seriesYData, new XYChart.Data<Double, Double>(null, Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(Line.y))), c);

int insertion_point = -(index + 1);
if (seriesYData.size() <= 0) {
    return;
}
List<XYChart.Data<Double, Double>> res = seriesYData.subList(insertion_point, seriesYData.size());

for (int ind = 0; ind < res.size(); ind++) {
    for (int pos = Bounds.x; pos > Bounds.y; pos--) {
        rffSeries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(res.get(ind).getXValue(), pos));
    }

}


}
```

please go through this link [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29819051/how-to-continuously-update-line-chart-with-live-data)

I asked same type question there also.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29819051/how-to-continuously-update-line-chart-with-live-data)

In line Chart 2, the peak values from line chart 1 should be shown, in such a way that, the values should continuously plot from top to bottom.

Comment: Are you sure you want to show all 1600 values at the same time?

Comment: @Uluk Biy yes, 1600 values i will get from real time device

Comment: You need to specify: are you rendering the graph yourself to an image, using some third party lib, or something else?

Comment: @Scruffy, he is using JavaFX, and within there is a component named LineChart.

Comment: @UlukBiy looking into it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague. Please post code.

This ought to be useful. [XYLinechart Move Left / Right](http://www.postseek.com/meta/7d21f859bfe65413e0f3c22eb553d4b9)

Below goes without knowledge of the fact that you are using JavaFx.

The best that I can do is suggest, assuming your x coordinates are integral and 0-1599, that you store your points as an `int[]`, with the array index as the x value, and each int value itself as the y value. This allows you to get the y value from the x value in one operation, but not the x value from y without checking the whole array.

```
Random rng = new Random();
int[] points = new int[1600];
for(int i = 0; i < 1600; i++) {
    points[i] = rng.nextInt(1600); // Between 0 and 1600
}
```