# Real-time JavaFX XYChart

Tags: javafx, real-time, updates

I am writing a quick charting application using JavaFX XYChart program. I would like the XYChart code to generate real-time updates to plots. From what I understand one  way to do this might be threw using concurrency or queues. Below is an example of a JavaFX XYChart, can you provide suggestions on how to make it such that there are real-time (moving) updates to the XYchart?

```
     import java.util.Arrays;
     import javafx.application.Application;
     import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
     import javafx.scene.Scene;
     import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
     import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
     import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
     import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
     import javafx.stage.Stage;
     import chart.gantt_04.GanttChart.ExtraData;

     // TODO: use date for x-axis public class GanttChartSample extends Application {

@Override public void start(Stage stage) {

    stage.setTitle("Gantt Chart Sample");

    String[] machines = new String[] { "Machine 1", "Machine 2", "Machine 3" };

    final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
    final CategoryAxis yAxis = new CategoryAxis();

    final GanttChart<Number,String> chart = new GanttChart<Number,String>(xAxis,yAxis);
    xAxis.setLabel("");
    xAxis.setTickLabelFill(Color.CHOCOLATE);
    xAxis.setMinorTickCount(4);

    yAxis.setLabel("");
    yAxis.setTickLabelFill(Color.CHOCOLATE);
    yAxis.setTickLabelGap(10);
    yAxis.setCategories(FXCollections.<String>observableArrayList(Arrays.asList(machines)));

    chart.setTitle("Machine Monitoring");
    chart.setLegendVisible(false);
    chart.setBlockHeight( 50);
    String machine;

    machine = machines[0];
    XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(0, machine, new ExtraData( 1, "status-red")));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, machine, new ExtraData( 1, "status-green")));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(2, machine, new ExtraData( 1, "status-red")));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(3, machine, new ExtraData( 1, "status-green")));

    machine = machines[1];
    XYChart.Series series2 = new XYChart.Series();
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(0, machine, new ExtraData( 1, "status-green")));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, machine, new ExtraData( 1, "status-green")));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(2, machine, new ExtraData( 2, "status-red")));

    machine = machines[2];
    XYChart.Series series3 = new XYChart.Series();
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(0, machine, new ExtraData( 1, "status-blue")));
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, machine, new ExtraData( 2, "status-red")));
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(3, machine, new ExtraData( 1, "status-green")));

    chart.getData().addAll(series1, series2, series3);           

    chart.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("ganttchart.css").toExternalForm());

    Scene scene  = new Scene(chart,620,350);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Possible duplicate of: [Line Chart Live update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22089022/line-chart-live-update)

Although since these solutions are quite polluted, I created a more minimalistic example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Main extends Application {

  private AtomicInteger tick = new AtomicInteger(0);

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) {
    final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();

    xAxis.setAnimated(false);
    xAxis.setLabel("Tick");

    yAxis.setAnimated(false);
    yAxis.setLabel("Value");

    XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<>();
    series.setName("Values");

    LineChart<Number, Number> chart = new LineChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);
    chart.setAnimated(false);
    chart.getData().add(series);

    Scene scene = new Scene(chart, 620, 350);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

    Thread updateThread = new Thread(() -> {
      while (true) {
        try {
          Thread.sleep(1000);
          Platform.runLater(() -> series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(tick.incrementAndGet(), (int) (Math.random() * 100))));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
      }
    });
    updateThread.setDaemon(true);
    updateThread.start();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

The chart's data is an observable list so you can add data from anywhere and it will update automatically. Just make sure to add your data within the UI thread.

Comment: OK. I have a similar example also for XYCharts line charts. Are you able to implement a solution for the bar chart. Perhaps, updating the series within the thread as per the following -- Thread updateThread = new Thread(() -> {
      while (true) {
        try {
          Thread.sleep(50);
          Platform.runLater(() -> series10.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(tick.incrementAndGet(), (int) (Math.random() * 100))));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
      }
    });