# JavaFX Realtime chart updates

Tags: multithreading, javafx, charts

This question has been asked before, multiple times, however I am still very confused as to how it specifically helps me.

I have a simple JavaFX XYChart.  I want to perform FFTs on live data and display the updates in realtime.  A lot more averaging will be done in the background, but essentially looking at 2-3Hz refresh rate on the chart.

I know there are other libraries and frameworks which make this easier, however they come with their own set of difficulties when working with javaFX, hence I would love to learn how to make this work for my needs.

So I have the following:

```
@FXML
public LineChart <Number, Number> midchart;

public void plotMidChart(){
    ArrayList freq = (ArrayList) Frequency.get(listViewIndex);
    ArrayList pha = (ArrayList) Phase.get(listViewIndex);

    for (int i=1; i<freq.size()-1; i++){
       phaseSeries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>((Number) freq.get(i), (double) pha.get(i)));
    }

    phaseSeries.setName("Phase");   


    midchart.getData().addAll(phaseSeries );
}
```

This currently works as a 'one pass' method. And each time I call plotMidChart I can update the chart with whatever data I have selected (via listViewIndex).  However this is currently quite slow to render and on the main thread.

Reading more, I have discovered that anything to do with changing the main JavaFX UI Thread should be called via 'Platform.runLater()) ->'
So I tried to put the method into the following code:

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    ArrayList freq = (ArrayList) Frequency.get(listViewIndex);
    ArrayList pha = (ArrayList) Phase.get(listViewIndex);

    for (int i=1; i<(freq.size()-1); i++){
        System.out.println(i);
        phaseSeries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>((Number) freq.get(i), (double) pha.get(i)));
        }
        midchart.getData().addAll(phaseSeries );
    });
```

Frequency and Phase are arrays of FFT results, so when I select a specific index, it returns the results for that FFT. However I am confused here, as surely all of the actual rendering is still being done on the main UI Thread. Isn't the point that it is done on another thread and just called to the scene on the UI thread?

I have read a bit about 'Task' but the oracle website still says this shouldn't be linked to the UI Thread.

I am also lost on how this is updating the current data.  Each time this is called, I want it to overwrite the current data series, so that only one series is ever displayed, and each time it is a brand new set of data (not being added to existing data).

The end goal is to have this on an infinite loop, sleeping for approx 300ms between each iteration.

I am calling this plotMidChart() method via the following

```
measureList.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){

    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        listViewIndex =  measureList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
        plotMidChart();
        }
}
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22089022/line-chart-live-update

Answer (score 2):

So there are multiple issues you are bringing up here and I will try to address them all.

First of all `Platform.runLater()` will execute the code you give to it in the UI thread. So you perform heavy operations in your own thread and everything that affects the UI needs to be called within `Platform.runLater()`.

What you could do is to create your data in your own thread and when this is done you give the result to the UI thread.

```
public void plotMidChart(){
    ArrayList freq = (ArrayList) Frequency.get(listViewIndex);
    ArrayList pha = (ArrayList) Phase.get(listViewIndex);

    List<XYChart.Data<Number, Number>> tempList = new ArrayList();
    for (int i=1; i<freq.size()-1; i++){
       tempList.add(.add(new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>((Number) freq.get(i), (double) pha.get(i)));
    }

    Platform.runLater(() -> {
       phaseSeries.getData().setAll(tempList);
    });
}
```

Also note that you don't need to call `phaseSeries.setName("Phase")` and `midchart.getData().addAll(phaseSeries )` everytime you recreate the chart data.

If your performance still is really bad, it is possible that you are giving too many data points to the chart which can take quite some time to render.

Comment: Ok, so the rendering probably is not the bottleneck in your application. But the smoothing itself could be causing performance issues.

Comment: I have tried as you suggested above.  I have moved the midchart.getData().addAll(phaseSeries) declaration into my initialize method, and have set the plotMidChart method as you have suggested above.  This seems to work on a first pass, and if I select an object as my data (using listViewIndex), my graph renders correctly. (reasonably quickly, I think I still need to lose data points).  However If I select another measurement the graph does not redraw.  I can confirm the listViewIndex updates, and the Platform.runlater in this method is called.   But the graph does not redraw.

Comment: Could you post the part of your code that is calling `plotMidChart()`? This should be part of a listener, i assume? (Maybe post the code as an edit to your question so the code formatting works)